# Create a DropDownMenu Item that dynamically adjusts widgets underneath

Tags: flutter

I want to create a dropdown widget similar to what you get on Google when you search something up, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g7c4.gif).

I'm thinking of having a `bool` to determine whether to show the item or not and to probably wrap the entire widget in an `Expanded` widget, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to build it. Also, I'm not sure what the best way to animate it would be.

I have looked at the `DropdownButton` and `DropdownMenuItem` classes, but that builds an overlay on top of everything, which is not what I want.

Before I create a custom widget, just wanted to know if anyone else has found any pre-made widget similar to what I'm trying to make, since I haven't been able to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is already a widget in Flutter. Take a look at [`ExpansionPanelList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) or even [`ExpansionTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).

Here's a Flutter's Widget of the Week video about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aJZzRMziJc